# java UDP and hamachi

Tags: udp, hamachi

I am doing a multiplayer game using UDP protocol (DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket). The program has to do client and server at the same time. This works fine on LAN networks, but I would like to make it work on Internet too. I have tried to use hamachi, but it doesn't work, the information goes only in one direction.

EDIT: Ok, I ask in another way. Is there any java class, program or anything else to connect two computers on internet using java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have just resolved the problem. It works fine with hamachi. I was copying wrong IP's, so it didn't work. If you exchange your IP's to each other, It works.